# How to deal with utf-8 string as i want to replace the — with space in my text and then use split function to separate each word from other word

Tags: python, python-3.x, string

I am trying to put all the words from a page in a string and then replacing `—` (utf-8) with space.
I am able to do so but when I do `split()` the words separated by space are taken together. For example, `about—it` --> `about it` after replace and then when I do split, the word that I get in the list is `'about it'` i.e without space.

I tried copying the `—` from the utf-8 format. It replaces it but doesn't change it.

```
book_content = book_content.replace('—', ' ')
book_content = book_content.replace('_', ' ')
book_text = book_content 
book_text = book_text.replace("\n", " ")
list_of_contents = book_text.split()
```

the output required is:

```
about it (readable string)
and ['about' , 'it']
```

Comment: Please _edit_ your question and show us clear, readable, sample input and the output you expect.

Comment: Can't reproduce. Please, provide a *reproducible* example.